# is it possible Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS with Sqlite syncing to MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, xamarin.forms, httpclient

Is it possible to sync Sqlite Backend in `xamarin.forms`(Android and iOS) to MySql `windows.form`? if yes, How? if not, what is the best way to sync mobile database to the system?

[SignUp Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NROcJ.jpg) [SignUp Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXH8T.jpg)
these are the screenshots of mobile application where i can register account , if i press register it will be saved to sqlite local database,
and i want to store the data to system in `windows.form` [System-Manage Accounts Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEHJ.png)

Comment: use some REST service for that

Comment: can you show me some example?

Comment: no because it is totally dependant on your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are asking a question about many things at once,

Here's where you should start with:

[PHP Insert Data Into MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

add tag for `MySQL` and `PHP` or whatever your server likes,

then have a look at [Consuming this data from your API using HTTPClient](https://github.com/ak47akshaykulkarni/Xamrin.Forms-HTTPClient-Get-Post)

once you know both of these things, you should be able to handle the database from MySQL and populate it in your xamarin application.

Additionally read about the difference between MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: Thank you i'll try this.