# How to Connect Xamarin Forms to MySQL database as backend of the app without webservice?

Tags: mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to Connect Xamarin Forms to MySQL database as backend of the app without webservice?

i'm using a  control panel website called myasp.net it offers a MySQL online database , and here's my [phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obkPk.png) i already set up all of the tables i needed, and i want to connect it to my xamarin forms application directly. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question also goes somewhat like this one I answered, and you are asking so many things with very few lines.

[is it possible Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS with Sqlite syncing to MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904377/is-it-possible-xamarin-forms-android-and-ios-with-sqlite-syncing-to-mysql/50905683#50905683)

again, you need to create an API to reach there.

**OR**

if it is a huge learning curve for you right now, you can get a free azure account and create an Azure Function, as [www.myasp.net](http://www.myasp.net) offer MySQL get the connection credentials.
 refer to this :

[Azure Database for MySQL: Use Node.js to connect and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-nodejs)

Comment: My huge problem is i can't create free azure acount because i don't have a card , and if i create azure student , i don't have also school email address .

Comment: @JeremyPaul then use the first link there